# Почему не работает скролл на колесико в низ и вверх?

Tags: vue.js, swiper

Подскажите , хотел подключить swiper , но столкнулся с проблемой , что не работает смена страниц при скроле колесика мыши в низ и в верх , что не так я написал ?

```js
<template>
  <swiper
    :direction="'vertical'"
    :slidesPerView="1"
    :spaceBetween="30"
    :mousewheel="true"
    :pagination="pagination"
  >
    <swiper-slide>Slide 1</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 2</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 3</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 4</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 5</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 6</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 7</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 8</swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide>Slide 9</swiper-slide>
  </swiper>
</template>
<script>
import { Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y } from "swiper/modules";

import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/vue";

import "./style.css";
import "swiper/css";
import "swiper/css/navigation";
import "swiper/css/pagination";
import "swiper/css/scrollbar";
// Import Swiper styles
export default {
  components: {
    Swiper,
    SwiperSlide,
  },
  setup() {
    const onSwiper = (swiper) => {
      console.log(swiper);
    };
    const onSlideChange = () => {
      console.log("slide change");
    };
    return {
      onSwiper,
      onSlideChange,
      modules: [Navigation, Pagination, Scrollbar, A11y],
      pagination: {
        clickable: true,
      },
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

```css
#app { height: 100% }
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;

  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-slide img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```